# Painfully slow local development

Tags: networking, vpn, sql-server, development

I know some may suggest that this question needs to be asked on StackOverFlow, but I do not believe this is not a Dev issue and probably an IT/Security thing. I will post this question on Superuser as well.

I am the newest developer in a company and I work remotely. I have received a top notch fast development laptop which is the same as everyone else.
This Laptop is connected to a USB-C to Lan adapter, then to a network switch, then to my router (all with Lan connection).

I use a VPN to connect to databases and whatnot. Among all developers, My environment has the slowest (by like 10~20X) performance. So every time I make a code change and recompile my code I have to wait 12~15min for things to load!

I have profiled my code and have noticed that SQL queries take painfully long time to execute.
A query that takes 70~90s to run on my machine through SSMS, takes less than 2s on other developers machines. (One of the developers lives in the same town as me and uses the same internet provider)

Some of the C# operations that take less than a ms to run on other laptops, take like 70ms~150ms on my machine.

Another developer and me pinged the same database server and we had comparable statistics, (delay, both zero packet loss, etc., similar internet speed after connecting to VPN) but still my queries took much longer to execute! The query is also a simple
 `Select top(10000) ID from someTable`

- I have disabled my Antivirus (again same thing on everyone's PC) and
  no luck!
- I have connected the laptop (via USB-C -> LAN hub) to my router (eliminating the switch), still no luck.
- I have modified my hosts file to point localhost to 127.0.0.1 to make sure these calls are not going outside and still no luck.
- I have pointed my Dev to other databases and no luck! everything still super slow.
- I have disconnected my Lan and used WIFI to connect to my router, still no luck!
- I have asked IT and they don't have a clue! I have done a whole bunch of other tests but I really doubt if it is something local!
- during run time I have given 'Realtime' priority to all Visual Studio/IIS/SSMS processes and still no luck.

What are the other things that I can ask our It to check and what are the other local settings/stuff that I can check?
Whatever it is, to me it seems that it knows what packets are going where and what their content is and can scan/delay them selectively!

I am going to disable Windows Firewall and see but I really doubt that it is the culprit.

Comment: I seriously doubt this is a question that can be treated sensibly in a Q&A forum. There's no way you can provide sufficient technical detail here for someone to even begin to speculate about possible causes for what you report. This is something that has to be pursued hands-on.

Answer (score 0):

Tilman is right.  We will most likely never figure this one out.  Too many variables all along the way.

Plug your computer directly into the cable modem. Bypass your router.  See if that helps.  Your router settings could cause latency.

Is your ISP bandwidth sufficient enough?  Run Speed tests. (again, directly from the modem)

The company's firewall could also be causing the issue.  The IT department should be willing to investigate a little bit.  At least enough to say hey, this isn't our problem.  Being an IT Manager I've seen it go both ways.

Is the sluggish performance just related to your development software?  Does the machine run well otherwise?

It's possible that you could have something misconfigured in your dev environment.  Something stupid like using an external address vs. a local address somewhere.  So that being connected to a vpn, you are sending that request to the vpn site, which then goes out to the internet only to come back in to the same vpn site and then back to your machine instead of going to the vpn site and back to your machine.

Is your dev file on a separate drive?  A lot of times, on more powerful laptops with second hdds, the second drive is a crappy one so the read/write latency on it is terrible.